# SCCM - Task sequence with application failure

Tags: enterprise, sccm, configuration-management

I have been having some issues lately when including applications in task sequences. When running any task sequence that contains applications, it automatically fails, and says "The referenced package cannot be found." I've checked my distribution points and boundary groups, and verified the application content is distributed. When checking the logs, it just states it failed to find an application, I track down the application it's referencing, and redistribute, or even remove it from the task sequence, and try running it again, I get the same error, except for the next application content ID's. When adding packages to a task sequence, it seems to run successfully. Has anyone else encountered this?

EDIT: I've also been seeing 'content hash value mismatch' errors in the logs.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Some extra info:

I have already restored the site server VM, rebuilt the distribution point.

Failed to find CCM_ApplicationCIAssignment object for AdvertID="***2017A", ModelName="ScopeId_E6E2F6FB-692F-4938-8AC6-146644EAE93F/Application_ce95b2ac-bf5a-4de2-b930-6f9b74b7dfd0"

"Failed to resolve selected task sequence dependencies. Code(0x80040104)"

Comment: Check whether your Applications are allowed to be installed during TS: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/brandonlinton/2014/01/30/enable-programs-and-applications-to-be-installed-from-a-task-sequence-without-being-deployed/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I verified this setting, and the applications are allowed to be installed, but the error still persists, unfortunately.

Comment: Does the TS install some Applications but not others?

Comment: I've noticed just a couple applications will install, but most will not. If I create and use packages of the main applications, and add them to the task sequence, it installs them successfully.

Comment: Since it's not all Applications that fail, I suspect the problem will be with the configuration of the offending Applications. I can't really diagnose further without seeing this first hand. Assuming these Applications work outside of TS(?) I would then attempt diagnose during TS, checking the Application has reached the machine etc: https://garytown.com/task-sequence-message-pause-with-no-package

Comment: The few applications that can install during a task sequence show up in Software Center as normal. The several various ones that cause failure will not show up in software center. I've also tried re-creating the applications and removing the problematic ones from each DP, and the problem persists. Been at this wall for a month now, currently in the process of rebuilding the site-server and DP. Wondering if this is possibly a bug in SCCM version 1902, as I've had a lot of issues right after updating the console from 1810.

Comment: I think there's your answer. If the Applications can't install outside TS then I wouldn't expect them to install inside TS. Since your other deployments are working ok this indicates there isn't a wider problem with your SCCM/DPs etc. I'd recommend debugging the offending deployments in isolation before re-adding to the TS. If you want community help with debugging the deployments it might be best to post them on ServerFault or SuperUser. Keep on chipping away!